# Permissions denied for Google Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to create a Cloud Scheduler but when I click on Cloud Scheduler, I receive the error: `There was an error while loading /cloudscheduler?folder=&organizationId=&project=my+project. You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:Project cloudscheduler.jobs.list`

When I check the permissions for the same project in my service account I see I have been granted all Cloud Scheduler permissions. Attached is the screenshot. [image]

Comment: The identity that you are using to access Cloud Scheduler does not have the required permission per the error message. Double check which identities you are using. Your question does not provide enough details to help further.

Comment: Where can I check the identities? I provided this much information, as this is where I stuck, and this is what is available to me. I need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and show what you are doing (the steps that you are performing). If you are using the Google Cloud Console, there is a person icon located at the top right of your browser. That will tell you the identity that you are using. If you are using a different tool, detail that in your question as well.

Comment: I am not using the console. I just clicked on the hamburger menu on cloud scheduler to create a scheduler through UI. Then I accessed my permissions through the Service account's permissions. That's it...

Comment: The Google GUI (Console) does not use a service account for authorization. You need to grant permissions to the user account that you logged in with.

Comment: John pretty much said everything about how to locate the account you are using in the Google Cloud console and about the use of the service account. Do you still have permission issues with the cloud  scheduler? The console is basically the user interface that appears after logging into [1]. So yes, when you click the hamburger menu, you are in the GCP console. [1] https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard

Comment: I was able to resolve it, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you, I have taken the information from the comments and made a community wiki answer so that it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates that the identity that you are using to access Cloud Scheduler does not have the required permission.

I recommend double-checking which identities you are using.

If you are using the Google Cloud Console, there is a person icon located at the top right of your browser. That will tell you the identity that you are using.

The console is basically the user interface that appears after logging from [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard).
So yes, when you click the hamburger menu, you are in the GCP console.